# python How to get tab names from QTabwidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I want to find Tab name and execute it. Running push button opens a new tab but I want to make sure this doesn't work as a redundant tab.
I want to create a source that looks for open tabs.

This is the Python code I am using.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(1020,800)
        self.toolbox = QToolBox(self)
        self.toolbox.setGeometry(QRect(10,20,191,361))
        self.page1 = QWidget()
        self.page1.setGeometry(QRect(0,0,191,175))
        self.push_button = QPushButton(self.page1)
        self.push_button.setGeometry(QRect(0,0,191,30))
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.new_page)

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tab_widget.setGeometry(QRect(210,20,801,771))
     def new_page(self):
        self.page_widget = QWidget()
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.page_widget, "product add")
        ......
```

I want to find the tab name and activate the correct tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        for i in range(self.tab_widget.count()):
            if self.tab_widget.tabText(i) == "product add":
                self.tab_widget.setCurrentIndex(i)
            else:
                pass
```

I found it very simply